# Getting the caret position on hover/dragover

Tags: javascript, input, drag-and-drop, caret

I am trying to get the **caret position** of the (rich)textbox I am **dragging** some text over.

The reason behind this is that I need to add some extra characters to the dropped text in my textbox, so I needed to prevent the default drop behavior.

```
function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var placeholder = document.createTextNode("[%" + data + "%]");
    event.target.appendChild(placeholder);
}
```

With `event.target.appendChild` the content is placed at the end of the textbox, so there should be a way to figure out what the position of the caret is when dragging/hovering.

This is where I'd like my text to be dropped:

[image]

Instead, it's added to the end of my input content:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the `drop`-event, I got it working by manipulating the `dragstart`-event.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("foo");

btn.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
};

btn.ondragstart = function(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "[%" + event.srcElement.innerHTML + "%]");
};
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span draggable="true" id="foo" class="btn btn-primary">Foo</span>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Is it possible getting such behaviour for ranges of selected text in the document? I tried many settings but had no possibility at all to edit dataTransfer, either in dragstart or drop events.